# Manipular Google Chrome com VBA

Tags: vba, google-chrome

Estou criando um código que entra no sistema online da minha empresa, porem ele só pode ser acessado pelo Google Chrome.

O código para abrir o Chrome é esse:

```
Sub Chrome()

    Dim GC As Object
    Dim WebUrl As String
    Dim NavigatorAddress As String

    Let NavigatorAddress = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    Set GC = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Let WebUrl = "http://endereço/do/sistema"

    Shell (NavigatorAddress & " -url " & WebUrl)

    GC.Document.all("vUSU_CODIGO").innerText = "login"
    GC.Document.all("vSENHA").innerText = "sennha"

    GC.Document.all("vUSU_CODIGO").form.all("BUTTON1").Click

End Sub
```

O código abre o Chrome no link certo e tudo mais, porem não consigo preencher o login nem a senha.

Comment: Nenhum navegador se deixa manipular como você quer, por motivo de segurança. Se isso fosse possível, não haveria atualização de sistema operacional nem de anti-malware que desse conta de todas as formas de ataque que isso possibilitaria.

Comment: Puts, é compreensível. Obrigado.

Comment: Man use um pouco de vbs e sendkeys que vc consegue preencher o usuário e senha facilmente sem usar Selenium nem python nem nada vbs é parecido com VBA uma pesquisa rápida por vbs sendkey e vc acha o que precisa

Answer (score 0):

Sei que esse Post é antigo, mas há um erro de lógica no mesmo. O objeto GC refere-se apenas ao objeto Internet Explorer criado pelo comando Create. NavigatorAddress e WebUrl referem-se ao Google Chrome. Mas, em momento algum há uma conexão entre e o Internet Explorer. Por isso, o Chrome é aberto normalmente. Enquanto há, também, a tentativa de se passar o usuário e senha para o Internet Explorer. Como disse o Nerd Laser, há, nesse caso,a possibilidade de utilizar o SENDKEYS (que também está presente no VBA). Existem também um programa chamado AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, você consegue abrir o google e manipular desse jeito

```
Sub test()
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

With driver

'abrindo o chrome

.Start
.Get "LINK DO SITE"
.Window.Maximize
```

Depois voce consegue manipular com:

```
.FindElementByXPath

.SendKeys
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Sim, é possível (há tempos!) automatizar procedimentos nos navegadores. No seu caso, o único componente que expõe objetos, propriedades e métodos é o Internet Explorer (uma rápida busca por "InternetExplorer.Application" já traz os resultados exatos com a explicação completa sobre o tema, direto da MS). Já os demais podem ser automatizados com o uso de outras bibliotecas, como a Selenium WebDriver (https://www.tomasvasquez.com.br/blog/microsoft-office/excel/vba-interagindo-com-paginas-web-com-o-selenium-webdriver). Boa sorte!

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)